# iOS display time as score and highscore on a UILabel

Tags: ios, nstimer, scoring

I'm having a problem when I'm trying to display the score as a highscore.

This is my code for getting the time ont the label on the correct format.

```
- (void)populateLabelwithTime:(int)milliseconds {

    int seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
    int minutes = seconds / 60;
    int hours = minutes / 60;

    seconds -= minutes * 60;
    minutes -= hours * 60;


    resultScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ds:%dms",seconds, milliseconds%1000];

    if (currentTime > highScore) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:currentTime forKey:@"highscore"];
        resultHighScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",highScore +10];
    }
    else {
    }
}

-(void)scoring {

   currentTime += 10;
   [self populateLabelwithTime:currentTime];
   highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highscore"];
}
```

The score format appears correct.
**score is: 1s:186ms**

but the highscore appears wrong
**Your highscore is: 1186**

know that this line is wrong

resultHighScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",highScore +10];

but I cannot figure how to make it work

any suggestions??

Comment: How is the highscore suppose to display? 1s:186ms?

Comment: You are retrieving the high score into an integer so it displays as an integer.

Comment: Yes this is the correct display "Your highscore is: 1s:186ms"

Answer (score 1):

This is the quickfix:

```
int newHighscore = highScore+10;

int seconds = ((int)floor((newHighscore)/1000));
int milliseconds = newHighscore%1000;

resultHighScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%is:%ims",seconds,milliseconds];
```

However I would highly recommend to change the way you handle the highscore

Comment: As noted above: Quickfix. This is suppose to hint the way. 
However you are 100% right @Zaph . I changed the code for better readability.